# The 2 terrorist chatroom cipher

Tags: cipher

you are finally here! We need your help, a group of terrorists have been talking to each other on their newly developed "HackerChat" app and we think they are up to something. Here are the logs:

```
Turn on logging... DONE
Pre-initializing...
LC: SET PROTOCOL... HTTPS.
AC: Encryption: OFF.
[Your network is not secure... consider enabling encryption] [WARNING]: [TURNING OFF ENCRYPTION IS DEPRECATED]
FileLock: ON.
All previous logs are being wiped......... 100%
IDB browser side enable.............. DONE
Removing IDB entries.......... DONE
Logging in previous users.... FAIL
[WARNING]: [LOGGING IN PREVIOUS USERS. NO PREVIOUS USERS FOUND. IS THIS THE FIRST LAUNCH?]
----------------------------------
======== HackerChat v0.0.1 =======
----------------------------------
User "Admin" logged in.
Admin: test
Admin: does this work?
Admin: right gonna get my other acc
User "Admin" logged out.
User "Rob" logged in.
---- 1 minute later ----
User "Jack" logged in.
Rob: right, is it working?
Jack: it's workin for me..
Rob: great, I spent all of last night working on this thing.
Rob: i've disabled encryption since we wont need it.
Rob: our net is private
Rob: and it's faster to get stuff in plaintext
Jack: mk
Rob: when are you ready for the missile launch
Jack: the what? what are you talking about...
---- 1 minute later ----
Jack: im worried about security..
Rob: oh right! Rotten apples!
Jack: can you fill the others with the remainin ones?
Rob: yes
Jack: ok
Jack: that reminds me of that other thing..
Rob: sure does
Rob: KCLFGKXASKARXNEGNBNOPMEOKXGLRYQMRLYFCLDXGWIHTPRY
Jack: CZFTQVLMMOCLLXZE
User "Rob" logged out.
User "Jack" logged out.
User "Admin" logged in.
Admin: FORCE_SHUTDOWN+WIPE
----------------------------------
======== HackerChat v0.0.1 =======
----------------------------------
Shutting down...
Deleting logs... FAIL
[WARNING]: [LOG FILES HAVE NOT BEEN DELETED DUE TO AN INTERNAL ERROR]
Shredding logs... FAIL
Awaiting action...
------------------
Admin: FORCE_DELETE
------------------
Force deleting logs...
FAIL. Force command line: rmdir /log
SEGFAULTAdmin: CANCEL
PROCEEDING WITH SHUTDOWN....Admin: CANCEL
LC: SET PROTOCOL... OFFLINE.
AC: Encryption: OFFLINE.
FileLock: FAIL.Admin: CANCEL
Removing IDB entries....... 100%
IDB disable...... 100%
Kicking users...Admin: CANCEL
----------------Admin: frick this is why i need to test this stuff
User "Admin" was kicked.
----------------
Disabling logs... DONE
```

Can you figure out what they are planning on?

**Hint:**

> Always
> cross eyes
> on the
> seemingly redundant
> thing on P.SE
> in most puzzles
> come on it's in every puzzle

**Hint 2:**

> Acrostic

**Hint 3:**

> The acrostic will tell you the encyption

Comment: Have a +1 just for the super-relatable end of the log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More complete answer working from @CodeLikeBeaker's answer.

(thanks for all the hints)

> The cipher used is the playfair cipher got it from the the first few lines around where it mentions that encryption is disabled and the hint - (PLAYFAIR)

From KCLFGKXASKARXNEGNBNOPMEOKXGLRYQMRLYFCLDXGWIHTPRY

> we get COMEATTENCENTRALPARKSHOXOTMISXSILESCOMEWITHGUNSX

We can break that into:

> COME AT TEN CENTRAL PARK SHOOT MISSILES COME WITH GUNS X

and from CZFTQVLMMOCLLXZE we get -

> OKAYIWILLCOMEROB or - OKAY I WILL COME ROB

so we know that

> somethings going to go down in central park at 10, with guns and missiles

I Think I still have a few issues from how the first encrypted line was broken up with needing to clean it a bit, so i'm happy for any suggested improvements.

Comment: Well done, we will all be safe from the terrorists now

Answer (score 1):

Partial Answer:

> going to take a stab at rotten apples. I'm guessing this is using rot10 on the word apples which gives the decode key (kzzvoc) for the encrypted text.

Comment: Close, but what's the encryption method?